# Como validar boton de wizard

Tags: php, wizard

Necesito ayuda, quiero que al momento de cambiar de paso en el wizard se valide autamaticamente (osea cargar la validacion ya hecha y que la leea el boton[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí])

Comment: y que has intentado?

Comment: Busque las librerias que trae la plantilla para almenos cambiar el color pero no la encontre y mi intencion es no dejar al proximo paso del wizard (osea al paso 2) si la validacion manda algubn dato incorrecto

Comment: No pongas tu código como imágenes, cópialo y pégalo como texto. De ese modo será más fácil leerlo y se podrá buscar y compartir una solución de manera más eficiente. Además, no crees varias preguntas para el mismo problema: edita tu pregunta original para añadir la información que faltaba y entonces se podrá reabrir. Edita la pregunta para añadir una descripción de lo que quieres conseguir y de lo que hayas intentado así como los errores/dificultades que te estés encontrando. Esta publicación es de muy baja calidad. Lee [ask] donde encontrarás información y consejos para mejorar tu pregunta.